# How to merge the 5 monitors in the XNA (fullscreen it)?

Tags: merge, xna, fullscreen, monitors

i need to merge 5 monitors in XNA (something like Eyefinity).
I have two graphics cards (HD 5450), which have DP connector, of course,
5x flat monitors with resolution 1024*768.

I need to merge/group this monitors in XNA, because i want fullscreen this over 5 monitors.
(fullscreen over multiple monitors)
I just need the visual studio to detect one graphics device with resolution 5120x768.

How i should modify GraphicsDeviceManager / GraphicsAdapter, make it work ?
I cant use Eyefinity, because i have two graphic cards and that i'm trying do "my own eyefinity" in xna.

In my app, i have 5 models dividing to 5 viewports, which are moved every 1024px.

OR, how i should to make it looking like a fullscreen. I don't want the border being visible and i want to have in the middle of screen - how center it ?

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest this is going to be difficult if not impossible to do using XNA. And you'd have to get so far outside of what the XNA framework is providing you that there would be little benefit in the end to even using XNA at that point.

Here's a great thread on the App Hub forums talking about different ways of potentially hacking around the XNA framework to achieve multiple monitor fullscreen using XNA.

http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/5562/571993.aspx

As you can see, no one really had any great suggestions and by the time you were dong you were basically programming at such a low level that you might as well be doing C++ and DirectX. Which is exactly what I would recommend to you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206364(v=vs.85).aspx

Using DirectX you can see that you're going to get a game/application running fullscreen with a multiple monitor setup much faster and without having to hack your way into it.